# DNSMasq unknown interface wifi0 - failed to start

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, ubuntu, hostapd

### Introduction

I am trying to use my Ubuntu Core-RaspberryPi as a Wifi Access point. Therefore, I am using **hostapd** and **dnsmasq**. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.cberner.com/2013/02/03/using-hostapd-on-ubuntu-to-create-a-wifi-access-point/) in order to setup everything.

**I start them manually - so all interfaces should be up and running when the services start.**

### HOSTAPD

**My hostapd.conf file:**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=my_ap
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=my_password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

**I added this line to /etc/default/hostapd:**

```
DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

### DNSMASQ

**I have the following dnsmasq.conf file:**

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.2,10.0.0.10,255.255.255.0,12h
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.dnsmasq
```

**My etc/hosts.dnsmasq file:**

```
10.0.0.1 raspbi
```

**My etc/network/interfaces file:**

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

### IP Address List Logs:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:46:24:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.68/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86207sec preferred_lft 86207sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe46:2490/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:13:71:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

### What I get

> If I then try to start my dnsmasq by running `systemctl start dnsmasq` I
>   get an error ***"unknown interface wlan0"***.

### What I tried

I also tried to force start **wlan0** by running `sudo ifconfig up wlan0` but still get the same error message

Comment: Is there maybe a space behind `wlan0` in your configuration file?

Comment: No there isn’t @jake

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to try [this setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/92303). You could also have a look at a [script](https://github.com/0unknwn/auto-hotspot) I wrote to automatically create [a hotspot if no other wifi is found](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100195).

Answer (score 3):

The Tutorial you used is not up to date as it was written in 2013 and seems to be written for normal Ubuntu not Ubuntu Core.

I never used Ubuntu Core but they seem to use `systemd-networkd`:

> By default network management on Ubuntu Core is handled by **systemd's
>   networkd** and netplan. While NetworkManager has some support to handle
>   netplan configuration files, Ethernet support is disabled by default
>   and has to be turned on explicitly to avoid conflicts with existing
>   network configuration. [Source](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/)

So I think you could mainly follow [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/92303).

Fiddling around with `/etc/network/interfaces` won't ever work in this context, I think.

Comment: Thanks for answering jake! I have now tried the tutorial you sent me and it looks quite okay. However, I can't see my Wifi and therefore can't connect to it. All services are up and running and I don't get any error logs. Do you have any Idea what I could do? I would comment on the tutorial but I don't have enough reputation yet... :(

Comment: @linus_hologram You could try to start hostapd manually and maybe see whats wrong there, but I think you really should try @Ingo's tutorial.
Could you add the ouput of `systemctl status networking systemd-networkd hostapd` to your question?

Comment: Sorry If I was unprecise in my comment. I tried your tutorial and think that this is the right way to go. Unfortunately, although I followed each step of the tutorial, I do not see a raspberry-pi WIFI network on my iPhone. So, somehow, the wifi network is not created. Also, I do not get any error logs or something so I really don't know where the problem is.

**I did the following tutorial steps:** 1) general setup; 2) Setting up a standalone access point; 3) Setting up an access point and with eth0, without routing;

I followed every step mentioned precisely but dont see my wifi.

Comment: Also, if you take a look at the _"Troubleshooting"_ part of the tutorial, and then reference to the _"wifi"_ section, you will find a command `sudo iw dev wlan0 info` which should return some information about the interface, especially **type AP**. If I run this command, I don't get **type** AP but 'managed'. Do you have any idea where I messed up or what the reason for the different type is?

Comment: Hi, I just read about your problems. Now we are mixing up two questions. This one you used old style networking but current discussing my tutorial using *systemd-networkd*. To not get confused it would be better you open a short new question, something like "I followed this tutorial <link> but have this problem ...". Then I will look if I can make an answer.

Comment: @Ingo thanks for you interest in helping me. I am now using ubuntu server on my raspberry pi and am still trying to setup a wifi access point. https://askubuntu.com/q/1170261/977546 would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @linus_hologram Sorry, but I don't have any experience with Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi.