# Can you switch from connecting the RPi from pifi access point to an actual router access point

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, wireless, ubuntu

So for a robotics project I have in mind I'm trying to create an access point on my rpi so that I can directly ssh into it without using wifi from another router. But the problem is that I'm not sure whether I can switch from the pifi access point back to my home router. I want to be able switch from my pifi access point to my router because I'd need to download libraries online. I tried using the Ubiquity Robotics rpi ubuntu image that has ROS preinstalled and I tried tinkering with the pifi thing in it but I couldn't use the internet even with an ethernet cable connect to the router. So I wanna know if its possible to switch from pifi access point to a router that i have at home, and if it is, then how do I go about doing it. Thanks in advance.

Please let know if i should elaborate a bit more.

Comment: please do not post same question at multiple sites https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/can-you-switch-from-connecting-the-rpi-from-pifi-access-point-to-an-actual-route?noredirect=1#comment31999_19459

Comment: What's pifi? Also, are you referring to connecting to the Pi vs your home router with your laptop, or re-configuring the Pi to be an access point or connect to your home router?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a **pifi** access point is but it is not necessary to switch anything. You can have an access point on the Raspberry Pi and also be connected with a WiFi client connection to your internet router. How to do it you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).

If you like to simplify the setup you can purchase an additional USB/WiFi dongle and use two physical WiFi interfaces. You can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866) doing this.

If you really have to switch the access point for some reason you may have a look at [Automatically Create Hotspot if no Network is Available](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100196/79866).